# Instagram API - How can I get the bios of people I am following on my account?

Tags: python, api, instagram

Firstly, I don't think the API allows me to get access to my followers/following list. I tried finding ways to do this, but they're all outdated.
I can get the bio of a specific user, but I need to do this for all the users in my following list.

```
import requests


user = "xxxxx"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': ''
}


r = requests.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{user}/?__a=1", headers=headers)
userinfo = r.json()["graphql"]

bio = userinfo["user"]["biography"]


print(bio)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instagram has no public API. There are tools like [Instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/) that can extract [followers](https://instaloader.github.io/module/structures.html?highlight=followers#instaloader.Profile.get_followers) and [followees](https://instaloader.github.io/module/structures.html?highlight=followers#instaloader.Profile.get_followees) of a given profile through scraping, but I would advise against doing that as scraping goes against Instagram's [Terms of Use](https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/1188470931252371).